# Hide button on completion of certain time duration

Tags: javascript, php, html, button

I want to hide a `submit` button on completion of 2 minutes of visiting that webpage. My code for this is following.

`<body>` is in `header.php` which is being called in all the pages of project,

```
 <body  onload="JavaScript:document.body.focus(); initSubmit();" onkeydown="return showKeyCode(event)">
```

I am coding the function `initSubmit()` in `form.php` as,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function initSubmit()
        {
            document.forms[0].elements['hideit'].style.visibility = 'visible';
            setTimeout( "document.forms[0].elements['hideit'].style.visibility = 'hidden'", 120000 );
        }

</script> 

    <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success wrp_submit_togle" id="hideit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" ></i> Submit</button>
```

This is not making the button hide. Can i know where I am going wrong ?

Comment: Do you have error in your console browser ?

Comment: I would just add a button using javascript and then when done, tell it to remove that button again

Comment: Did you try to put your script tag below the button tag?

Comment: @Inazo console says initSubmit() not defined.

Comment: @Vermicello What a conclusion !!! Bang on. Worked so swiftly. But may I know logic behind this.

Comment: @Ansh That because the script is executed before the button is loaded.

Comment: @Vermicello Thanks alot. Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number one flaw in code is accessing element using document.forms[0]. By only allowing one of each ID on a page, getElementById can accurately retrieve it, every time, without caring about what happens to the document in the meantime.

Getting element only single time and using it by assigning as a variable is always economical if it need to be used more than once.
For Quick result I decreased time for button to get visible.

Call `initSubmit` on `window.load` as follows;

```js
function initSubmit() {
        var s = document.getElementById( 'hideit' );
                s.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                setTimeout( "document.getElementById( 'hideit' ).style.visibility = 'visible'", 5000 );
 }
    window.load = initSubmit()
```

```html
<form>
  <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success wrp_submit_togle" id="hideit">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" ></i> Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Call the function  `initSubmit` on `window.load`

```js
function initSubmit() {
  document.forms[0].elements['hideit'].style.visibility = 'visible';
  setTimeout("document.forms[0].elements['hideit'].style.visibility = 'hidden'", 5000);
}


window.load = initSubmit()
```

```html
<form>
  <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success wrp_submit_togle" id="hideit">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" ></i> Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this . but it seems this also does not works. I have done `    <script type="text/javascript">
       
 function initSubmit()
 {
  document.forms[0].elements['hideit'].style.visibility = 'visible';
  setTimeout( "document.forms[0].elements['hideit'].style.visibility = 'hidden'", 5000 );
 }
   window.load = initSubmit();
</script> `